# Why am I unable to modify 'this' in this context?

Tags: javascript, this

In the following case, I would assume that the value of `this` (which is a string) could be modified to a different string. That way, I could emulate an array and simply write `string_var.shift()` to remove the first character of the string. However, from what I've gathered, this is immutable. I'm not sure how else I would approach this problem if I am unable to modify the value of the string. I could of course return the result but then I'd have to write `string_var = string_var.shift()` which has a different syntax to the array function of the same name and would ultimately be confusing.

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "shift", { value: function() {
     this = this.substr(1)
}})
```

Comment: `this` is not a variable, it's a keyword. It's syntactically invalid to assign anything to it. It's impossible to implement a mutation method on the `String` interface anyway, strings are immutable in JavaScript.

Comment: Why are strings immutable though?

Comment: Because the ECMAScript specification says so.

Comment: Good enough for me!

Comment: because they are literals, in your example it is like when you say var "hello" = "Hi";

Comment: @SaymoinSam that's not a logical argument. There exist array literals and object literals, yet they're mutable.

Comment: those are references!

Comment: @SaymoinSam then say that. The concepts of "literals" and "references" are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify `this` since it is a keyword, not a variable. Just like `function` or `class`

you can assign that value to another variable:
`var self = this.substr(1)`
instead

Also, note that `this` context is the inner function at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why the following code won't work. `this` is not a variable, it is a property of an execution context (global, function or eval) that, in non–strict mode, is always a reference to an object and in strict mode can be any value. It is syntactically invalid to assign anything to it.

But more importantly, it is impossible to implement a mutation method on the String interface, as strings, booleans and numbers are all immutable within Javscript, as per the ECMAScript specification. When you "mutate" a value, such as in the context `x += 5`, behind the scenes you are creating a new value, not modifying the original one.

Comment: There is no "behind the scenes". The semantics of `x += 5` can be explained using only the ECMAScript specification, without resorting to implementation details. `x += 5` is equivalent to `x = x + 5`. The identifier `x` is reassigned to a new reference which is the result of evaluating `x + 5` using the previous reference value of `x`. All variable identifiers in JavaScript can be thought of as references, not values.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can return the value after doing some operations on it

```js
String.prototype.shift = function() {
  return this.slice(1);
};

var a = "abcdef";
console.log(a);
a = a.shift();
console.log(a);
```

**Note:**
modifiying the prototype of the language itself is considered to be bad practice

Comment: If you read, the asker already enumerates this approach and explains why they didn't like it.

Comment: I'm just letting this for someone else who has the same need in the future :)